# Filter out rows with common field where at least one fulfills a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data like this:

| Task | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | 123 | Open |
| Task2 | 123 | Closed |
| Task3 | 211 | Closed |
| Task4 | 211 | Closed |
| Task5 | 564 | Closed |
| Task6 | 994 | Open |

I want to delete rows with the same IDs that have 'Open' status. In other words I want to delete all IDs that have 'Open' status.

The end result will be like this:

| Task | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task3 | 211 | Closed |
| Task4 | 211 | Closed |
| Task5 | 564 | Closed |

Data:

```
{'Task': ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3', 'Task4', 'Task5', 'Task6'],
 'ID': [123, 123, 211, 211, 564, 994],
 'Status': ['Open', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Open']}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could change the title (and maybe even the content) to something that can be found with search engine by others having a similar problem

Comment: I agree with you, what would be your suggestion for a title?

Comment: I'll try: "filter out rows with common field where at least one fulfills a condition in pandas" (note that some would argue that "in pandas" has to be left out, since there the question is already tagged with "pandas")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could take the Open Statuses and `groupby` + `cummax` to create a boolean filter.

The idea is if a Status is Open, we flag its corresponding ID as True for all rows it appears, then we filter out all such rows:

```
out = df[~df['Status'].eq('Open').groupby(df['ID']).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
    Task   ID  Status
2  Task3  211  Closed
3  Task4  211  Closed
4  Task5  564  Closed
```